# .htaccess rewrite /dir/sub to /dir

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have files in /directory/subdirectory and I'd like it to appear to users that they're in /directory.

Here's what I have in my .htaccess file at the moment (returns 500 error):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*) directory/subdirectory/$1 [NC,L]
```

I know that rewritebase could accomplish this if my files were in the root www directory but I can't do that for this project.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `[NC,L]` at the end of your rewriterule line. NC indicates that this rule is case insensitive, and L indicates Last, that's where the engine stops processing the rules.

For more info visit [ModRewrite cheatsheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/)

Comment: If it returns 500 error, it might be your script is failing or not printing the proper headers to the browser, shouldn't be a mod_rewrite issue. Check out your server logs and that might shed some light into this

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule (?!^directory(/.*|)$)^(directory)/(.*)$ $1/subdirectory/$2 [NC,L]
```